Didn't vent my pressure canner correctly
I didn't vent my pressure canner for 10 minutes. I thought it was 5. Can I reprocess my ground beef or will it ruin it? I have the new presto pressure canner.

Does this answer your question? Why let a pressure canner vent, before putting the weight on?
